# position view on specific point left or right of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm trying to control the width, height and position on screen of a view via seekbars.
Until now I've manage to control the width and height but I have problems to set the position on screen.
The way I'm using which works is via radio group to set gravity LEFT_TOP, LEFT_CENTER etc, with the use of LayoutParams:

```
mParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
```

and same for center,bottom, right etc.
But I want to have more control and set the vertical position with the use of left(for left side of screen) and right(for right side) seekbars.
I tried this way:

```
mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | (screenHeight -seekBarProgress)
```

and the same for right side, but I get strange behaviour.

Comment: Why are you doing a bitwise OR operation with the value of screenHeight-seekBarProgress?

Comment: Because Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, puts the view in top left, so I assumed that the Gravity.LEFT will put it at the left side and the "(screenHeight -seekBarProgress)" will control the vertical position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT |`<strike>`(screenHeight -seekBarProgress)`</strike>

You can't apply arbitrary values to the Gravity property as you did above. You can only use predefined constant values which you can find here: [Gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html).

Thus, you cannot move a view to an arbitrary position by changing GRAVITY.

Comment: Thanks, you know another way?

Comment: You can use location properties but that depends on the layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using layoutParams, and I think I found a way by using gravity and x,y:

```
mParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        mParams.y = 24;
```